# How to parse xpath from soap response to retrieve key value pair

Tags: xml, bash, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet, xmllint

Using bash I am trying to extract id and name as key value pair from below soap response and want to store this pair in csv file.
Below xmllint command is returning unwanted values as I am not able to provide the filter.
Can anyone please help.
I am open to use xmllint and xmlstarlet.

xmllint command that I tried:

```bash
xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='getAllUserApplicationsResponse']/*[local-name()='return']/*[local-name()='name']/text()" request.xml
```

Elements to be extracted:

```xml
    <ax2159:id>396112</ax2159:id>
    <ax2159:name>com.example.app.name</ax2159:name>
```

**Please note that `<ns:return></ns:return>` is a repeating element.**

Soap Response:

```xml
<ns:getAllUserApplicationsResponse
    xmlns:ns="http://application.app.api.admin.abc.example.com"
    xmlns:ax2179="http://logging.app.api.admin.abc.example.com/xsd"
    xmlns:ax2169="http://stagingarea.app.api.admin.abc.example.com/xsd"
    xmlns:ax2159="http://types.core.api.admin.abc.example.com/xsd"
    xmlns:ax2171="http://permission.common.app.api.admin.abc.example.com/xsd"
    xmlns:ax2161="http://application.app.api.admin.abc.example.com/xsd"
    xmlns:ax2183="http://component.app.api.admin.abc.example.com/xsd"
    xmlns:ax2173="http://resinstance.app.api.admin.abc.example.com/xsd"
    xmlns:ax2165="http://status.app.api.admin.abc.example.com/xsd"
    xmlns:ax2176="http://svars.app.api.admin.abc.example.com/xsd"
    xmlns:ax2187="http://binding.app.api.admin.abc.example.com/xsd"
    xmlns:ax2155="http://exception.core.api.admin.abc.example.com/xsd"
    xmlns:ax2156="http://fixer.core.api.admin.abc.example.com/xsd">
    <ns:return
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax2161:ApplicationShortDesc">
        <ax2159:id>396112</ax2159:id>
        <ax2159:name>com.example.app.name</ax2159:name>
        <ax2161:environment xsi:type="ax2159:EntityIdentifier">
            <ax2159:id>6175</ax2159:id>
            <ax2159:name>app_environment</ax2159:name>
        </ax2161:environment>
        <ax2161:folder xsi:type="ax2159:EntityIdentifier">
            <ax2159:id>34148</ax2159:id>
            <ax2159:name>MYAPP</ax2159:name>
        </ax2161:folder>
        <ax2161:runtimeState>Running</ax2161:runtimeState>
        <ax2161:runtimeStateEnum>RUNNING</ax2161:runtimeStateEnum>
    </ns:return>
</ns:getAllUserApplicationsResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task, you could consider using [xq](https://github.com/kislyuk/xq). It can read XML and write CSV, and takes care of all the quoting and escaping.

```bash
xq -r '."ns:getAllUserApplicationsResponse"."ns:return"
  | arrays[] // . | [."ax2159:id", ."ax2159:name"] | @csv
' request.xml
```

```
"396112","com.example.app.name"
```

Comment: xq is really great. I am bit worried because 'ax2159' might change with change in product version. Is it possible to convert this xml to json? API returns invalid JSON if I try to put 'accept: application/json' header.

Comment: @Ranjeet Sure. In fact, xq internally already converts the input into JSON, then lets [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq) take over all the heavy lifting. The filters used here are actually written in jq's own DSL, which is a very powerful JSON processor (including reex matching to find "changing names"). The conversion to CSV with `@csv` (which includes the quoting and escaping) is also part of it (see [here](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#format-strings-and-escaping)). For just the conversion to JSON, use the identity filter `.` as in `xq . request.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `xmllint` shell taking namespaces into consideration

```
printf "%s\n" "setrootns" 'cat //ns:return/*[name()="ax2159:id" or name()="ax2159:name"]/text()' 'bye' | xmllint --shell test.xml
```

Raw result

```
/ > setrootns
/ > cat //ns:return/*[name()="ax2159:id" or name()="ax2159:name"]/text()
 -------
396112
 -------
com.example.app.name
/ > bye
```

Filtering unwanted lines with `... | grep -vE '^\/ >| ---'`

Result

```
396112
com.example.app.name
```

Xpath can be written also as (probably better)

`//ns:return/ax2159:id/text() | //ns:return/ax2159:name/text()`

Comment: You don't need parenthesis to pipe it to xmllint. It is even counter-productive as parenthesis spawns a shell. If you really need to pipe the output of multiple commands, you use curly braces and add a semicolon after each command inside the curly braces. But here it is not needed at all: `printf "%s\n" 'setrootns' 'cat //ns:return/*[name()="ax2159:id" or name()="ax2159:name"]/text()' 'bye' | xmllint --shell test.xml`